# CORS issues in Angular 5 SPA

Tags: angular, typescript, http-post, cross-domain

I am building an Angular 5 .NET Core SPA with Visual Studio 2017 and I am trying to make some **http.post** calls. For example:

```
@Injectable()
export class ValidateEmailService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    validateEmail(email: any) {
        const headers = new HttpHeaders().set("Content-Type", "application/json");
        const url = "https://service/.../Email/Validate";
        return this.http.post(url, email, { headers: headers })
            .catch(error => Observable.throw(error || "Server error"));
    }
}
```

Since I am using a local web server, I faced cross-origin problems when trying to call the above API. I installed CORS Chrome plugin as to overcome that. Unfortunately, then I faced other problems:

> OPTIONS https://service/.../Email/Validate 405 (Method Not Allowed)
>   Failed to load https://service/.../Email/Validate: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:65040' is therefore not allowed access.
>   The response had HTTP status code 405

The above API works fine at Postman. Is there any solution to the above? No matter how much I did search, I did not find a workaround...

P.S. Please do not suggest to go through C#. I want to call the API directly.

Comment: why downvoted, quick downvoter mind explain for that?

Comment: CORS needs to be enabled on the server side. Do you have access to the web api code? If yes you can enable CORS and try.

Comment: This is a very standard CORS error. Take a look at the ASP.NET Core [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors) for setting up your server and generally understanding why this is fine in Postman, etc.